# MS Graph API filter on forceChangePasswordNextSignIn

Tags: api, filter, graph, azure-active-directory

In Microsoft Graph, I want to list users who have forceChangePasswordNextSignIn turned on.

The [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries) state that `passwordProfile/forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` is filterable, but if I run

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=passwordProfile/forceChangePasswordNextSignIn%20eq%20true

I get...

```
"error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'forceChangePasswordNextSignIn' of resource 'User'.",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $filter queries requires a special header that is consistencylevel:eventual and the $count=true in the end of the query.
[image]

Try with the query:`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=passwordProfile/forceChangePasswordNextSignIn%20eq%20true&$count=true`

Refer the [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#legend), Hope this helps.